# user_pseudo_id changed without app re-install

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I import firebase analytics logs to BigQuery, and observed the user_pseudo_id changed unreasonably. As I put a "UUID" in user profile in their own app, and found some events are bundled with same "UUID", can have different user_pseudo_id. And I'm pretty sure the users didn't re-download or re-install the app.

Especially, sometimes, I saw the user_pseudo_id changed from A to B, and later changed back to A.

Any hints/instructions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same behavior. I guess the id would also change if the user clears local cache. I now assume user_pseudo_id can change over time and use other more durable ids to map them. I've never seen it change backwards though, would be an interesting case.